# Dataframe numbers stuck as string during format manipulation

Tags: r, string, dataframe, matrix, type-conversion

I have a large dataset which is composed of measurements from two species. I need the results as numbers in a matrix for some analysis, but somehow through trivial manipulation of the dataframe the numbers get converted to strings and cannot be directly converted back into a matrix. To be clear, I repeat the main steps below:

```
df<-data.frame(
X1=c(1,2,3),
X2=c(4,5,6),
X3=c(7,8,9)
)

med1<-c("name1", "name2", "name3")
rownames(df)<-med1

df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(t(df), species=c("inv1", "inv2", "inv3")))
```

The new dataset df2 cannot be reversed the same df as a matrix if the added column is removed. I cannot do operations with the restored dataframe.
class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
class(df2)
[1] "data.frame"

```
 as.matrix(df)+1 #this operation works fine
 as.matrix(t(df2)[1:3,])+1 #this doesn´t work as figures seem fixed as strings
 as.matrix(df)==as.matrix(t(df2)[1:3,]) #but logic operator says they´re identical?
```

Please, what is happening, and how can I recover df from df2 as a full numeric matrix?

Comment: Your use of `cbind` is using `cbind.matrix`, which when combining with `species` is forcing everything to be strings. If you really want to use `cbind`, then use it on a `data.frame`, not on the matrix returned from `t(.)`, such as `cbind(data.frame(t(df)), species=c("inv1", "inv2", "inv3"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cbind` on a *frame*, not on a matrix. Note that

```r
class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(t(df))
# [1] "matrix" "array"
```

so the S3 method of `cbind` called on `t(df)` is using the `cbind.matrix` method on dispatch. This keeps it all numeric, which is fine, until you try to combine with the `species` vector of *strings*, which then up-converts all numbers to strings.

Solutions:

1. `cbind` on a frame, not a matrix, such as:

   ```r
   df2 <- cbind(data.frame(t(df)), species=c("inv1", "inv2", "inv3"))
   class(df2)
   # [1] "data.frame"
   str(df2)
   # 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
   #  $ name1  : num  1 4 7
   #  $ name2  : num  2 5 8
   #  $ name3  : num  3 6 9
   #  $ species: chr  "inv1" "inv2" "inv3"
   ```
2. Avoid `cbind`, just `transform` it (if using base R):

   ```r
   df2 <- transform(data.frame(t(df)), species=c("inv1", "inv2", "inv3"))
   ```

In which case, you can recover the original `df` with:

```r
data.frame(t(df2[,1:3]))
#       X1 X2 X3
# name1  1  4  7
# name2  2  5  8
# name3  3  6  9
```

Comment: Great, I didn´t know transform yet, but looks like it works perfectly !

Comment: It's the base R equivalent (loosely) to `dplyr::mutate`, in case you're familiar. It works great with native pipes (`|>`) as well, if that's of interest. Glad it helped.